# Wordpress built in custom fields don't validate or sanitize? Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: custom-field, security

I'm surprised to see that when creating post meta using the default/built in custom fields on the post editor page it allows you to enter tags like:

```
<a>,<script>,etc.
```

I then realized you can also enter:

```
<script> </script>
```

into the post content box. Is there a way to hook into the validation and make it so that script can't be entered?

Am I wrong in thinking that a hacker with access to the backend could use the fields to get malicious script to the database?

I guess I'm just a bit confused because when using the settings api ( or even creating custom metaboxes ) there's so much emphasis put onto proper validation/escaping. Yet, on post pages you can enter whatever you want? Thanks!

Comment: If an intruder already has acquired access to the admin backend, post content validation should not be one of your primary concerns...

Comment: Imagine you don't get what you've passed to that custom fields...

Comment: That's true, I guess I just don't understand why validation and sanitation are stressed so much with settings/custom meta boxes when the same can be said in those situations too.

Answer (score 2):

Unfiltered HTML in post content and title is a capability usually reserved for admins. If you don’t want to allow that for your users, don’t make them admins.

Sanitation of custom fields has to be provided by the code author. There are use cases for such fields where entering JavaScript code is a *desired feature*. Again, if you don’t want that, disable it.

This is not a security issue: you can control everything, and you should not install code you didn’t read and understand. That part is not WordPress specific. :)

Comment: What do I hook into in order to disable it?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support this should do the trick